# Javascript bit masks

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I've used bit masks in Java (not Javascript) before, but it's been a while and it's making me bug out.

This is the Typescript I'm wanting to work with.  Theres 3 roles,

```
enum Type {
    FRUIT = 0x1,
    VEGGIE = 0x2,
    BOTH = FRUIT | VEGGIE
}

class Thing {
    role:number;

    constructor(role:Type){
        this.role = role;
    }
    getRole(){
        return this.role;
    }
    is(role:Type) {
        return !!(this.role & role);
    }
}

var whatever = new Thing(Type.FRUIT);

console.log('fruit', whatever.is(Type.FRUIT));
console.log('veggie', whatever.is(Type.VEGGIE));
console.log('both', whatever.is(Type.BOTH));

// fruit true
// veggie false
// both true
```

I conceptually see why "both" is coming back as "true", but my bit math isn't great.

When the role is either `FRUIT` or `VEGGIE`, the others are false.  When it's set to `BOTH`, all should be true.

Tried a few combinations of shifts and bit operations, but I can't get that output.  If I try them separate it's fine, but I'd like to use combinations of bits to build.

Comment: Just introduce a new class `Type` with `isFruit` and other flags. JS is not the language when you ought to use bitmasks and bit arithmetics.

Comment: @zerkms why are you discouraging bitwise arithmetic in JavaScript? I've used it a number of times with great success--you just have to be aware that bitwise operations are limited to 32 bit integers in JS.

Comment: @dave any reason to prefer bit arithmetics over just boolean flags in JS? What is the technical reason to over-complicate the solution?

Comment: What is your question exactly? The code looks fine to me

Comment: @zerkms if it's two or three static fags then boolean can be fine. If you're dealing with lots of flags thenot it is convenient to consolidate into one property. They also gives you flexibility to add a new flag without altering your data structure.

Comment: Think in binary, (`this.role` VEGGIE) `10` `&` (`role` BOTH) `11` gives (VEGGIE) `10`, then `!!10` is `true`, so a _`this.role & mask` is truthy_ test means _"at least some of the mask is in role"_ or _"at least some of the role is in mask"_ , i.e. _"mask and role overlap"_. What you really want to test is that `role & mask === mask`, i.e. _"all of mask is in role"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> return !!(this.role & role);
> ```

Your version works as `isAny`, but you want it to work as `isAll`:

```
return (this.role & role) === role;
```

Comment: While this answer may actually contain the correct code, it really needs a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 7):

When you perform a bitwise `&` operation the result is that the bits turned on in both values used in the expression.

For example (taken from [Pro TypeScript](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Typescript-Application-Scale-JavaScript-Development/dp/1430267917), p 207)

```
a 1011
&
b 1101
= 1001
```

The first column, both values are "switched on (1)", so the result is also switched on. The second column, `a` is switched off, so the result is `0`, the third column `b` is off, so again a `0` and finally the last column both are on, so a `1`.

In your case, it is even simpler because you are dealing with such small numbers...

```
a 01 // FRUIT
&
b 11 // ALL
= 01 // FRUIT
```

So the result is `01`, or `1` if you have ten fingers.

If you use a double-bang `!!` to convert `1` to to a boolean (I call this [slacker parsing](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/02/slacker-parsing-in-javascript/)), you'll get `true` because `1` is truth-y. This doesn't answer the question you were really asking, which is "does this bit flag match".

This is why `this.role & role === role` is the correct code, because you won't get a mistake from the "truthiness" of the value `1`.